# Extracting multiple strings from different elements with the same class bs4 beautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from a site that has different div but the same class name.

```
<div class="release-date-text-wrapper" >
                        <div class='release-date-title'><a href="/pharrell-x-adidas-nmd-hu-sesame">Pharrell x adidas NMD Hu Sesame</a></div>
                        <div class='release-date-style'>Sesame/Sand-Bright Red</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                                <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 release-date-item-continer clear-padding'>
                <div class='release-date-item-wrapper'>
                    <div class="release-event-date-wrapper">
                        <div class="event-date ">
                            <div>
                                25&nbsp;Oct                            </div>
                            <div>2020</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='release-date-image-wrapper'>
                                                <a href="/pharrell-x-adidas-nmd-hu-crystal-white" class='thumbnail'>
                                                        <img  src="https://4app.kicksonfire.com/kofapp/upload/events_master_images/thumb_ipad_pharrell-x-adidas-nmd-hu-crystal-white.jpg" alt="Pharrell x adidas NMD Hu Crystal White" class="img-responsive imagecache imagecache-kofapp_list"  width="250" height="200" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="release-date-text-wrapper" >
                        <div class='release-date-title'><a href="/pharrell-x-adidas-nmd-hu-crystal-white">Pharrell x adidas NMD Hu Crystal White</a></div>
                        <div class='release-date-style'>Crystal White/Clear Mint-Shock Yellow</div>
```

I am trying to pull the 'release-date-title' from the 2 divs they should show as the following

```
Pharrell x adidas NMD Hu Sesame
Pharrell x adidas NMD Hu Crystal White
```

Here is current code I use.

```
Name = soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'release-date-title'}).text
```

This gives me the first one no problem, the trouble I am having is getting the 2nd one. I tried .find_next("div") but it showed the class 'release-date-style'.

EDIT:
I need to be able to select them individually as later on I will be adding them to a discord embed adding colors and dates to each title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using soup.find which returns the single item, use soup.findAll which returns a list of all matching results. That way you can iterate through the results to get what you need.

```
Names = soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'release-date-title'})
for name in Names:
    print(name.text)
```

prints:

```
Pharrell x adidas NMD Hu Sesame
Pharrell x adidas NMD Hu Crystal White
```

Per our comments below here is how you would print result #4:

```
Names = soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'release-date-title'})
print(Names[3].text) #Change this index to get the result you want, right now it is 3 since you wanted result #4
```

Comment: While this works, I need to find them individually as I will be linking them up to a discord embed with colors and dates to go with each item.

Comment: @Lukemul69 I'm not sure I understand what you mean by individually. You could just separate the result out by the index of what you're looking for. Ex: `Names[0]` would equal `Pharrell x adidas NMD Hu Sesame` and `Names[1]` would equal `Pharrell x adidas NMD Hu Crystal White` Is this what you mean?

Comment: Oh okay that would work. Could you give me an example on how to separate the results? There are about 20 or so titles. So lets say I wanted to print item title 4 how would I write that in the code you sent above?

Comment: @Lukemul69 I edited my comment to print title 4. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If `html_doc` is your HTML snippet from the question, then this script:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for t in soup.select('.release-date-text-wrapper > div:nth-child(1)'):
    print(t.text)
```

prints:

```
Pharrell x adidas NMD Hu Sesame
Pharrell x adidas NMD Hu Crystal White
```

---

CSS selector `.release-date-text-wrapper > div:nth-child(1)` will select first `<div>` child directly under element with `class="release-date-text-wrapper"`

---

Or:

```
for t in soup.select('.release-date-title > a'):
    print(t.text)
```

---

Or:

```
for t in soup.select('.release-date-title'):
    print(t.text)
```

Comment: While this works, I need to find them individually as I will be linking them up to a discord embed with colors and dates to go with each item.